# const { data } = useQuery problem: I want data to be object initially

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client, react-hook-form

I'm trying to implement a login function to my react app.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useQuery, useLazyQuery, useMutation } from "@apollo/client"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"
import { LOGIN } from '../queries/queries'

const Login = () => {

   const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState({})
   const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(LOGIN, {
      variables: {
         email: formValue.email,
         password: formValue.password
      }
   })


   const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm()
   const onSubmit = (value) => {
      setFormValue(value)
   }



   if (loading) return <p>loading</p>


   return(
      <>
         <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} >
            <input 
               type="text"
               name="email"
               placeholder="E-mail"
               ref={register}
            />
            <input 
               type="password"
               name="password"
               placeholder="Password"
               ref={register}
            />
            <button type="submit">
               Login
            </button>
         </form>
      </>
   )
}
```

When I code `console.log(data.user)` for example, error happens because `user` is not undefined.
I know I can get object from `data` if I code variables directly, but I want to get it after handleSubmit.

I think if I can make `data` object initially, error would not happen.
Then is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try "data?.user" instead of "data.user" when referring to that object attribute
the question mark should disable the error if the object doesnt exist

update:
you can also try declaring data as an empty objec literal:
{ loading, error, data = {} }